# Can an URL shortener pass parameters?

Tags: url, redirect

I use bit.ly to shorten my urls.
My problem - paramters are not passed.
Let me explain I use http://bit.ly/MYiPhoneApps which redirects (let's say) to http://iphone.pp-p.net/default.aspx
Now when I try http://bit.ly/MYiPhoneApps?param=xx this param is not added to the resulting url.
I know I could create an extra "short url" including a paramter - so http://bit.ly/WithParam would result in http://www.mysite.com/somepath/apage.aspx?Par1=yy and so forth.

But what I want is to have a short URL directing to a page - and then I want to add a parameter to this shortened url - which shoul (of course) land at my page.

Is this a shortcome of bit.ly (and others are maybe able to do it) - or does "parameter forwarding" not work with 301 redirections?

Manfred

Comment: On the pricing page of bitly, they have a paid option for the enterprise plan: Parameter Passing - Keep your link parameters intact when you shorten links containing URL codes. I have yet to fully understand what that means through.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no technical reason why it couldn't be done. The service would simply have to look at what parameters it is being sent, and then rewrite the target URL accordingly.

The problem is that it's not necessarily well defined how to do that.

Suppose you have the url `http://example.com/default.aspx?foo=bar`, and it has the short url `http://foo.com/ABCD`. What should happen if you try to access `http://foo.com/ABCD?foo=baz`? Should it replace the value, so you get `foo=baz`? Should it append it to make `foo=bar&foo=baz`? If we include both, which order should they be in?

The system cannot know which parameters are safe to override and which are not, because sometimes, you DO want both of them in the URL, and it may matter what order things are added in.

You could argue "Well, just don't allow this for URLs where parameters are already present", but there's also the issue that it's going to complicate the process a lot more. Without this, you just lookup a key in a database and send a redirect header. Now, you need to also analyze the URL to check for parameters, and append part of the URL you were called by. That requires more system resources per redirect, which may become a big problem if your service is used very frequently - you'll need more server power to handle the same amount of redirects. I don't think that tradeoff is considered to be "worth it".

Comment: I would expect it to become `foo=bar&foo=baz`, FWIW (the parameters added to the short url should come after all the parameters part of the long url).  I think this would yield sane results in most cases.

Comment: So it is technical (as I thought) possible - but some kind of a "logistic" or "how to handle" problem. If anyone knows a (stable) service whichs allows parameter adding please let me know.

Comment: @ManniAT: Umm, 8 years late, but it looks like [ClickMeter (and maybe others?) supports this](https://support.clickmeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/211032666-How-can-I-pass-variables-parameters-to-the-destination-URL-).

Comment: Umm, 8 years late (number 2), and [tinyurl.com](https://tinyurl.com/) can do this.

Comment: I mean if you're opting in for that purpose, why'd you set target url w/ param in first place? doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 20):

As mentioned in comments by [rinogo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114558/rinogo) and  [Jurgen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110608/jurgen)

In [Clickmeter](https://support.clickmeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/211032666-How-can-I-pass-variables-parameters-to-the-destination-URL-)

> ```
> Destination URL : www.yoursite.com?myparam1={id1}&myparam2={id2} 
> Tracking link   : www.go.clickmeter.com/38w2?id1=123&id2=abc 
> After click     : www.yoursite.com?myparam1=123&myparam2=abc
> ```

In [TinyUrl](https://tinyurl.com)

> ```
> Destination URL     : http://x.com?a=1
> Shorten URL         : https://tiny url.com/y6gh7ovk
> Shorten URL + param : https://tiny url.com/y6gh7ovk?a=2
> Resultant URL       : http://x.com/?a=1&a=2
> ```

Added space to post tinyurl

Comment: The problem I am facing is I have shortened the fixed part of several paypal long urls to hide the email param from spam, however appending &<series of params> won't work, if I put tinyurl.com/XYZ?<series of params>  it won't work may be because the expanded URL will have two ? marks the 1st from the expanded email. Any ideas, thanks

Comment: SEEN THIS? https://tiny url.com/y6gh7ovk?a=2; ONLY ONE '?' IS THERE. REMOVE SPACE

Comment: I did see that. However, when I try my example at tinyurl I get forwarded to paypal and it fails at paypal.  I never get to see what the actual url is expanded to. So, how can I see the expanded URL? I could not find this feature at tinyurl. I believe your example is clear and working for you but not in my long URL case.  How can I debug?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

URL shortening associates a unique key based on a full URL (parameters and all), so it is not possible to pass parameters to a shortening service.

Typically

`http://iphone.pp-p.net/default.aspx?param=10`

must produce a different key to

`http://iphone.pp-p.net/default.aspx?param=22`

'Parameter forwarding' is simply not possible in these kinds of redirects, as parameters are not valid parts of a shortened URL is most (if not all) services.

Comment: Of course it's *possible*. OP's intention is not to have two target URLs map to exactly the same short URL - one key would still only map to one target. He just wants the service to manipulate the target using *additional* information provides as parameters. The two things are quite different.

Comment: Of course it's possible  - if you're the service provider and build your service to allow that. But the OP talks about bit.ly specifically. And bit.ly nor any other current URL shortening service I know of does support parameter forwarding on short URLs.