# Shorten RESTful API using URL shortener

Tags: web, url, bitly

Can I shorten the following URL from

https://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/csl-apidev/servepdf.php?dict=VCP&page=3867,a

to something like

bit.ly/abcde?dict=VCP&page=3867,a ?

What I tried:

I tried to shorten https://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/scans/csl-apidev/servepdf.php to
bit.ly/abcde

And then invoked
bit.ly/abcde?dict=VCP&page=3867,a

But it failed. The arguments did not get passed.

Edit:

My question is not restricted to any particular URL shortening service in particular. My question is whether it is possible to shorten such REST APIs or not. If yes, how?

Comment: How is a support request regarding the use of a proprietary URL shortener on topic here per the scope of the site defined in the [help/on-topic]?

Comment: My request is not for solution which must be proprietary in nature. It was just a reference.

Comment: Question is whether such REST APIs can be shortened ? If yes, how? I am not able to find much detail on searching the web. To use X service or Y service is immaterial to the problem. Sorry, if I did not make myself clear in the question.

Comment: Perhaps https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask? (vide https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572749/can-an-url-shortener-pass-parameters Seems to have useful solutions. (via lalitAlAlitaH)